# Powershell - Extract data from a file depending on a 2nd file data

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract some data from one file compared to what is found in  another file. I need this to happen in Powershell. I'm really trying to coax some SQL like workings, and as much as I've scratched my head, read on the subject, I've not been able to make anything happen.

Essentially, I need to match 4 criteria from file 1 to 4 Criteria on file 2. If those match, I need to ensure 2 other criteria on file 2 meet certain values.

If the criteria match and the values are met, I want those transactions in one file, otherwise in another file.

Criteria to match from file 1 to file 2:

- Company number: `$_.File1Field1` to `$_.File2Field4`
- Transaction number: Last 4 digits of `$_.File1Field8` to `$_.File2Field1`
- Transaction value: `$_.File1Field11` to `$_.File2Field10`
- Transaction Date: `$_.File1Field7` to `$_.File2Field7`

If those 4 criteria are a match, I need 2 extra fields on the file 2 to NOT be, say,  "ABC" or "DEF" for `$_.File2Field2` & "1234" for `$_.File2Field3`.

Then I need all transaction of one type in one file, and the others in another file. 
Am I asking too much of powershell (I certainly am asking too much of myself with that one!!!!  lol )?!?

I've done a lot of reading on Compare-Object, Where-Object, but couldn't find anything that I could put to use. :(

Those are my original files at the moment.

```
#File 1:
$LoanTransactions = import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Test_Store_Loans_Module.txt
#File 2:
$LoanExtract = import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\loans_extract.csv
```

I've done where-object in the past, where I would pre-define some conditions and then apply that the a file to extract the result, but I haven't been able to make the conditions depends on something contained in my 2nd file.

Something like that:

```
$ConditionsToMeet = { $_.File1Field1 -eq $_.File2Field4 -and $_.File1Field8 -eq $_.File2Field1.....}
$ConditionsNotMet = { $_.File1Field1 -ne $_.File2Field4 -or $_.File1Field8 -ne $_.File2Field1.....}

$LoanTransactions | where-object $ConditionsToMeet | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract1.txt

$LoanTransactions | where-object $ConditionsNotMet | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract2.txt
```

Obviously, my conditions aren't constructed properly, unfortunately, despite extensive reading, I couldn't find how to. 
It may be super simple, or perhaps Powershell just cannot quite do that, but i thought this should be achievable?

Comment: [does this help at all?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5598/how-do-i-diff-two-text-files-in-windows-powershell) It's essentially the equivalent of the unix ```diff``` command which seems to be what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @cyberstems, sorry, i couldn't find anything in that link that I could put to use (myself anyway!). Some interesting stuff there though.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that Company Number, Transaction Number, Transaction Date, and Transaction Value are *guaranteed* unique identifiers for each row values. In other words, they would constitute a key in an SQL table. Frankly, my assumption is that Transaction Value isn't actually a part of the key and instead it's a data consistency check between the two files. If either of these assumptions is incorrect, this solution may not work for you. However, if that's the case, then your problem is potentially non-deterministic. That is to say, your data files may not have enough information to actually solve the problem.

`Compare-Object` isn't going to work well here. It's a very flakey command and doesn't behave very well in most applications.

The easiest answer is probably going to be, "load your data files into an SQL database and run a query." Ultimately, that's probably your best option, even if you're looking at using an SQLite database.

However, let's say you had to do this with PowerShell. The easiest way to do that is to do take the dead simple, brute force approach:

```
#File 1:
$LoanTransactions = Import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Test_Store_Loans_Module.txt
#File 2:
$LoanExtract = Import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\loans_extract.csv

# Find all transactions to save to Extract1
$Extract1 = foreach ($Tran in $LoanTransactions) {
    foreach ($Extract in $LoanExtract) {
        if (
            ($Tran.File1Field1 -eq $Extract.File2Field4) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field8 -eq $Extract.File2Field1) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field11 -eq $Extract.File2Field10) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field7 -eq $Extract.File2Field7) -and
            ($Extract.File2Field2 -notin ('ABC','DEF')) -and
            ($Extract.File2Field3 -ne '1234')
        ) {
            $Tran
        }
    }
}

# Find all transactions not in Extract1 and save them to Extract2
$Extract2 = foreach ($Tran in $LoanTransactions) {
    $FoundInExtract1 = $false
    foreach ($Extract in $Extract1) {
        if (
            ($Tran.File1Field1 -eq $Extract.File2Field4) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field8 -eq $Extract.File2Field1) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field11 -eq $Extract.File2Field10) -and
            ($Tran.File1Field7 -eq $Extract.File2Field7)
        ) {
            $FoundInExtract1 = $true
        }
    }
    if (-not $FoundInExtract1) {
        $Tran
    }
}

$Extract1 | Where-Object $ConditionsToMeet | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract1.txt -NoTypeInformation

$Extract2 | Where-Object $ConditionsNotMet | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract2.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

You can probably be smarter about it by using hash tables as indexes to speed up the process. Basically, what we're going to do is load the `$LoadExtract` into nested hashtables. Hash tables make for *very* quick key lookups. Building the table should be relatively quick. Using a local database table that has 6 fields in the primary key, it took about 12 seconds to process 175,000 records, but your mileage may vary. There are a lot of variables here.

Once it's built, the script will fairly easily be able to do lookups in File2 against the values in File1. The code will be kind of ugly, but it should perform about as well as PowerShell can.

The next thing to remember is that `Import-Csv` imports everything as plain text. That means *formatting including trailing spaces in important*. Additionally, hash tables are data type aware. `$hash[1234]` is different than `$hash['1234']`. You will not do lookups correctly if the data types and data values don't match *exactly*, so you need to be very certain that your fields that you're using for a key are exactly the same. The only thing you don't have to worry about is case sensitivity. Everything else matters because there's no implicit data conversions.

Note that in my code below I accidentally swapped the Transaction Date and Transaction Value. This doesn't actually affect anything in how it functions, but it makes it a bit more confusing. I blame the really terrible field names.

First, we'll set up our hash table from file 2:

```
#File 1:
$LoanTransactions = Import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Test_Store_Loans_Module.txt
#File 2:
$LoanExtract = Import-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\loans_extract.csv

#Hash table to be used for Loan Extract lookups
$LoanExtractTable = @{}

#Build the loan extract table nested hash table
$LoanExtract | ForEach-Object {
    # Company Number
    if (!$LoanExtractTable.ContainsKey($_.File2Field4)) {
        $LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4] = @{}
    }
    # Transaction Number
    if (!$LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4].ContainsKey($_.File2Field1)) {
        $LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4][$_.File2Field1] = @{}
    }
    # Transaction Date
    if (!$LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4][$_.File2Field1].ContainsKey($_.File2Field7)) {
        $LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4][$_.File2Field1][$_.File2Field7] = @{}
    }
    # Transaction Value
    # This is the last key, so we save our data here.
    if (!$LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4][$_.File2Field1][$_.File2Field7].ContainsKey($_.File2Field10)) {
        $LoanExtractTable[$_.File2Field4][$_.File2Field1][$_.File2Field7][$_.File2Field10] = $_
    }
}
```

So, if we have a company number `57`, with a transaction number `123456`, a transaction date of `2019-11-30`, and a transaction value of `123.45`, you could look it up like so:

```
$LoanExtractTable['57']['123456']['2019-11-30']['123.45']
```

Note again, everything here is explicitly a string. The formatting is important on the date and the currency value. In the code below, however, we'll need to go back to `ContainsKey()` and nested if statements again because we need to look for existence of records. If it feels like we're building an SQL style index and doing a join, it's because we basically are.

Now, we can iterate through the transactions file.

```
foreach ($LoanTransaction in $LoanTransactions) {
    $ValidExtract = $false
    # Company Number
    if ($LoanExtractTable.ContainsKey($LoanTransaction.File1Field1)) {
        # Transaction Number
        if ($LoanExtractTable[$LoanTransaction.File1Field1].ContainsKey($LoanTransaction.File1Field8)) {
            # Transaction Date
            if ($LoanExtractTable[$LoanTransaction.File1Field1][$LoanTransaction.File1Field8].ContainsKey($LoanTransaction.File1Field7)) {
                # Transaction Value
                if ($LoanExtractTable[$LoanTransaction.File1Field1][$LoanTransaction.File1Field8][$LoanTransaction.File1Field7].ContainsKey($LoanTransaction.File1Field11)) {
                    # It's in the LoanExtract file! Now we can do our additional data checks
                    if (
                        $LoanExtractTable[$LoanTransaction.File1Field1][$LoanTransaction.File1Field8][$LoanTransaction.File1Field7][$LoanTransaction.File1Field11].File2Field2 -notin @('ABC','DEF')
                        -and $LoanExtractTable[$LoanTransaction.File1Field1][$LoanTransaction.File1Field8][$LoanTransaction.File1Field7][$LoanTransaction.File1Field11].File2Field3 -ne '1234')
                    ) {
                        # It's valid to export to Extract1.txt
                        $ValidExtract = $true
                        $LoanTransaction | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract1.txt -Append -NoTypeInformation 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($ValidExtract -eq $false) {
        $LoanTransaction | Export-Csv \\774512-LRBSPT01\********$\uardata\rt1\BankRec\Test\step1\Extract2.txt -Append -NoTypeInformation 
    }
}
```

There's definitely room for optimization and improvement here. I have no idea what your data looks like, but I have to think the order of fields above is pretty awful. I would think Transaction Date, Company Number, Transaction Number, Transaction Value would work much better.

Additionally, you could easily move the tests for `File2Field2` and `File2Field3` to where you're building the hash table, but I can't be certain that's everything you're doing.

The way the data is written out isn't extremely optimal, either, but it's probably better than iterating twice or using array concatenation with `+=`. At least this can use the disk buffer.

The above code is **not** simple, but it's about as simple as I can think to make it without making PowerShell iterate through File2 for every row of File 1 (i.e., do a Cartesian product) which could be extremely slow if both files are large.

Comment: I didn't have the time to try to put your examples in use today unfortunately. I'm hoping to have some tomorrow. Your example #1 is amazing. I couldn't have written it, but I understand how you make it work and seems to be exactly what I need. Your example 2 seems good too, though for some reason, I prefer #1. I will need to implement both to see if I can get the same exact outputs. Very exciting!!!! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Oh, and I thought having non descript field names would be simpler...... lol In the real files, the fields have actual names. :D